# What is the largest aircraft ever put in a spin?

Tags: spins

What is the largest aircraft, by weight, ever deliberately put into a spin?

Comment: Mil Mi-26 or Zeppelin I believe. It's relatively easy and kind of inevitable during normal operation.

Comment: I suppose the op is asking about fixed-wing...

Comment: @Sanchises I thought the previous comment was a joke.  But in case it is not, the definition of spin includes the stall of a wing, so it must have a wing.